# C# - How to run multi await in one method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I don't know how to run multi await methods in single method. For example my code as below:

```
      public static async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        bool authen = false;
        string message = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            session = await FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
            fbAccessToken = session.AccessToken;
            fbFacbookID = session.FacebookId;
            await saveProfile(fbFacebookID); //error here,my app is closed at here
            authen = true;

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            authen = false;
        }
        return authen;
    }
```

And I have method save profile

```
  public async static void saveProfile(string fbFacbookID)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fbFacbookID))
        {
            response=await StaticClass.getJsonStream(string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/{0}", fbFacbookID));
            JObject _object = JObject.Parse(response);
            SaveValueSetting("usernameFB",(string)_object["username"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

But I cannot run  `method`? So how do I fix it?

Comment: Why can't you run `method`? Are there exceptions? Compiler errors? Please include the definitions of `method1` and `method2`.

Comment: Put `async` after `public` and add `()` after the called method names.

Comment: Fix the example code. You are not calling the methods.

Comment: @ Euphoric , @ Nico Schertler : I have just edit,please review again

Comment: It's likely that `saveProfile` throws an exception. Have you stepped through the code and checked if everything is in order?

Comment: If these are called during "lifetime events", then an `await` will inform the OS that you're done processing that event. The easiest fix is to use a deferral (if your OS supports it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned code.

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyMethod();
        MyMethod1();

    }
    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
        //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 

        //and now we call await on the task 
        int result = await longRunningTask;
        //use the result 
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
    public async Task MyMethod1()
    {
        Task<int> longRunningTask = SecondMethod();
        //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 

        //and now we call await on the task 
        int result = await longRunningTask;
        //use the result 
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
    public async Task<int> LongRunningOperation() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); //5 seconds delay
        return 1;
    }

    public async Task<int> SecondMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. He asked why his code does not work. Instead of answering this question, you responded with "Don't know. Just take this code. It probably does not do what you want, but it works."